# how to split a string into sequences defined by a rule with range v3 library?

Tags: c++, algorithm, range-v3

I have a string of vehicle number, for example `kz083y68` and i want to convert it into `kz 083 y 68` with spaces. String also could be `3486nv09`, etc, so there is no fixed position to split. All i need is to split subsequences of numbers and letters by spaces.

Obviously this can be done manually, but I'm wondering if there is a function in the range-v3 library for this. In general, maybe there is a function that takes some predicate (`isdigit`, `iseven`, `isdog`) and splits given range to corresponding subrange?

Comment: `views::split_when`?

Comment: `views::chunk_by`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `views::chunk_by` to get a set of sub-views:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string_view plate_code{"kz083y68"};
  auto views = plate_code |
            std::views::chunk_by([](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
              // Thanks @Jarod42 for the simplified predicate!
              return std::isdigit(lhs) == std::isdigit(rhs);
            });
  for (auto const view : views) {
    fmt::print("{}", view);
  }  // ['k', 'z']['0', '8', '3']['y']['6', '8']
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/3P3sfPovv).

You can use `views::join_with` to get a single view with a selected delimiter:

```
int main() {
  std::string_view plate_code{"kz083y68"};
  auto view = plate_code | std::views::chunk_by([](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
                return std::isdigit(lhs) == std::isdigit(rhs);
              }) |
              std::views::join_with(' ');
  fmt::print("{}", view);
  // ['k', 'z', ' ', '0', '8', '3', ' ', 'y', ' ', '6', '8']
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/MhWh6TdGv).

Comment: With the help of the Boost.Hof library and a lambda that lifts the `xor` operator, one can easily get to write `auto views = plate_code | chunk_by(eitherButNotBoth(is_digit));`, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/dKnPM3c6W).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! Enlico: I'll keep my answer without the Boost.Hof's lift, but feel free to add that variation as a separate answer.

Comment: @Enlico: we don't want `xor` though but `==` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks. In which case the lambda is not needed as we have `std::equal_to{}`. Thanks, I've posted is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of sharing a way to make [the already proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76868222/5825294) a bit (imho) neater, closer to spoken English, only by using existing abstractions, specifically [`boost::hana::on`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-functional.html#ga35c4fc3c5677b9f558150b90e74d3ab1) from [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) and [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html) from [Boost.Hof](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/hof/doc/html/doc/index.html), together with some `using`.

The buisness-logic line is just

```cpp
auto views = plate_code | chunk_by(equal ^on^ is_digit);
```

It sounds a bit like: *"chunk by `equal`ity applied `on` the whether each `is_digit`"*.

But `equal` is just a synonym for `std::equal_to{}`,

```cpp
constexpr auto equal = std::equal_to{};
```

and `is_digit` is an object wrapping `std::isdigit` by means of Boost.Hof,

```cpp
constexpr auto is_digit = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::isdigit);
```

so no further logic was written by me, I've just reused existing building blocks.

Complete example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/34x4dPxro).

Comment: Interesting but a bit strange solution with ^-^) thank you

Comment: [Louis Dionne](https://github.com/ldionne), author of Boost.Hana, most likely took inspiration from Haskell for the name of this combinator. In Haskell, you'd write ``(==) `on` isDigit`` (even though, Haskell's [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) is a bit less general than Boost.Hana's).